# How much cpu does an Android App need to consume to be cpu-intensive?

Tags: java, android, cpu-usage

I need to write a few cpu-intensive Android applications. One I have already coded is a BigInteger factorial but it consumes totally around 30-40% of my cellphone cpu. My phone is hexa-core and the cpu-usage is about 5% kernel and 30% user. Is this enough for a cpu intensive application or should the percentage be very high like 80-90%? It also consumes about 120MB memory out of the available 260MB. Is that fine or it must be very low?

Comment: What is considered CPU intensive is relative to the user. There's not a single metric where you can simply say an application is CPU intensive or not.

Comment: Thanks @Lie Ryan! Then what about the memory consumption?

Comment: same thing, it depend on the phone, the type of application, the user's personality, and what other things that the user is doing. What's the reason for the question?

Comment: I explained it above. I am investigating some cpu-intensive Android applications and need to create the apps myself. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. This is both a straightforward question and a tricky question. First off, 30%-40% is not that CPU intensive; actually, it's pretty wimpy. I'm guessing that one of two things is happening: (1) your application isn't running enough threads to keep all the cores fat and happy, or (2) the OS has some built in governors to keep any given app from dragging down the phone, making it pretty much useless and giving the manufacturer a very bad name. (By the way, I don't know if the developers implement (2) or not. If I was the designer, I would.)

Is your app an android compliant Java application? Or are you running closer to the metal?

Comment: My app is running different number of threads up to 128 threads. Yes its an android compliant Java application.